# Can literally everyone attain Moksha?

Tags: gods, philosophy

All these concepts regarding Nitya-samsaris and tamo-yogyas sound sadistic and cruel, to say the least, and akin to Abrahamic religions. If the supreme God is so merciful and all-able, then shouldn't he save absolutely everyone, and never keep anyone away from him?

Comment: Could you share the references for Nitya sansaris and tamo yogyas and which Abrahamic concepts they are similar to and why?

Comment: According to advaita, Brahman is always one at all times and all observations are like projections of that Brahman. Ishwar is neither angry nor merciful to anyone, because it's one and same, so there is no question of saving one or keeping it at bay. It is our illusionary perception that when we feel sorrow we believe God is punishing us, or rewarding when we're happy. These are mere karmaphal of our own. Aatma and parmaatma are just witnesses to it.

Comment: @sbharti Abrahamic faiths have eternal damnation, similar to the concept of tamoyogyas in the Madhva sect. Nitya-samsaris can never attain salvation, according to Vishistaadvaita and Dvaita

Comment: You do not attain moksha, you have moksha already, you just do not realize it. Everyone is free

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who CAN'T attain moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55603/who-cant-attain-moksha)